# How to remove every n-th element from dataframe column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am using python and have a pandas dataframe imported from a csv. I would like to remove every nth value from each entry in a specific column.

For example:

- the dataframe column to transform is called:

  "Linestring"

  - each entry has a varying float lengths and goes like this: `Linestring(151.420 -33.540, 155.464722 -39.069046, 153.30925678 -33.08364825, 152.0998 -31.8090, 150.539067 -30.57578)`
- each entry has varying lengths
- I would like to remove say every two elements after each comma giving: `Linestring(151.420 -33.540, 153.30925678 -33.08364825, 150.539067 -30.57578)`

Attached/linked is a visual guide of what I am after.

Example problem and outcome

[image]

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: What is Linestring? Is it a Shapely object? If so, perhaps you should look into how to remove every Nth element in a linestring. Then you can look at how to apply that function to all rows in a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Hi @jkr sorry, I was supplied the Linestring data as a csv. I am not familiar with Shapely but will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I hope it'll help.

```py
df['Linestring'] = df.Linestring.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.split(',')[::2]) if ','.join(x.split(',')[::2])[-1] == ')' else ','.join(x.split(',')[::2]) + ')')
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex it works! I am rather unfamiliar with these functions so I'll try to break it down and leave a comment on how I think it works. :)

Comment: @Alex - please add some explanation to this answer. At the moment it is code only without explanation.

Comment: @jkr, it is apparent that OP hadn't genedrated this CSV file and is not the author of the idea to store a rather complex `Linestring` object with its parameters in a cell of a former pandas DataFrame in a text (csv) file (instead of, for example, pickle). It is also apparent that OP isn't going to work with the result of this string operation. Somebody formulated this task. OP needs a solution to do this strange task. I gave a solution. A solution in a total mess of handling data, storing python objects, and working on tasks with no final goal, which I might see on the horizon.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to replace every nth value with None, you can then drop these values leaving you with a new data frame that does not include these dropped cells.  I hope this helps.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Numbers': [10,15,33,22,17,77,9]}) #a dataframe with column and some values
print(df) #prints the original dataframe

def rmNth(dFrame, col, n): #dataframe, column, delete every 'nth' 
    rows = len(dFrame.axes[0]) #stores the number of rows
    x = n - 1 #used in the while loop

    while (x <= rows): #replace every nth cell with a null value
        dFrame.at[x ,col] = None
        x = x + n #increment x by n

    print(dFrame) #prints the dataframe showing all cells that will be removed are replaced with 'nan'
    newDF = dFrame.dropna() #remove null cells
    newDF.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) #reset the index
    return (newDF)

print(rmNth(df, "Numbers", 3)) #print the data frame with every 3rd value removed from the Numbers column
```